# Strange behaviour starting process with init script

Tags: linux, debian, mongodb, init.d

**I'm seeing some strange behaviour when starting a process with an init script.  Most likely I am doing something stupid, but perhaps someone could let me know what might cause this behaviour:**

*[Background: the process is mongodb's monogod running as a config server (2.4), and I'm running on Debian 6.  The process runs under user 'mongodb', and I'm issuing commands via SSH as a non-root user]*

- When the server is booted, the process appears to start normally (I can see it via ps -ef, and there is a mongodb.pid file generated).
- If I try to stop the process via `sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb stop`, then the weirdness begins : I get `mongodb apparently not running`. (The process and the pid are still there though).
- Of course, if I try to `sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start` now I get 'failed' and an error in the log about the port already in use, which is to be expected as there is actually already an instance running.
- If I kill -15 the process and then try `sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start` I get more weirdness: In the console I get `Starting database: mongodb failed!` (no more info).  But... the process is now running and in the logs I don't see any errors, it just looks as if the process has started normally.
- If I try to stop this process with  `sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb stop` I get the `mongodb apparently not running`.

**The script in question is [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/init.d).**

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: In case it's something mongo related, here is my mongodb.conf for the config server:

```
configsvr=true

dbpath=/data/configdb

logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend=true

port = 28222
bind_ip = a_public_ip,127.0.0.1,a_private_ip

auth = true
keyFile = /srv/mongodb/keyfile

nohttpinterface = true

fork = true
```

Additionally: I'm seeing `Starting database: mongodb failed!` during the boot screen (but still there is a process seemingly running normally after boot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one instance running on that server, or something else that might be putting another value here:

```
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
```

That would cause the problem you are seeing here, it will be looking for the process with the ID that is in that file to determine if `mongod` and what PID to stop when shutting it down.

You should also take a look at the permissions on that file to make sure that the process can access it and update it when it is starting up.

Basically, we need to have separate $NAME values for each init script you are using to avoid collisions, and make sure that the right PID value is making it into that file for the service to work as expected.

If everything looks good, then I would guess you are hitting the issues described here:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7254

numactl being invoked (as it should when installed) seems to cause the incorrect PID to be written to the PID file.  We're looking for feedback troubleshooting this one, so if you could add your experience (and whether you have numactl installed) that would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  There should only be one instance running on this machine (the config server mongod) and as far as I can see that is the case.  Regarding permisions on the PID file - its root/root with readonly permissions for everyone else - should this be different? If so, I wonder why I havent seen this problem on other machines.  The only other thing I;m thinking is maybe the fork=true in the config - is that a potential problem?  I've added the config file to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm - it seems that if I boot fresh, the process id in the PID file is different from the one reported by ps -ef. (The pid file value is slightly higher).  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: I think you are hitting the bug I added to the answer, looks like a numactl related issue.  If you are on a non-NUMA machine, you could take a look at the patch here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8774 (for a NUMA enabled machine you should make sure mongod is run with numactl).

Comment: Ah - it certainly seems to match those symptoms, thanks!  At least I know what it is now :)  I will log into jira and add what I can.

Comment: Regarding NUMA - I'm afraid I don't know anything about this.  It's a 64 bit Linode VPS instance. Is there any way I can check?

Comment: ah, then numactl is installed (detected by the init script) but I believe the Linode instances are Xen VMs so I think you are OK. If in doubt, have a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/471204/how-can-i-tell-if-numa-is-enabled-on-a-mongodb-server

Comment: Yes, Xen VMs. I just ran the command in that linked question and see `NUMA turned off`.

Comment: In that case, the patch I mentioned above (which essentially stops the script from using numactl) should be a valid workaround for you until we fix the root issue with the bug.  Just be aware that the init script may get overwritten if you upgrade at a later date.

Comment: Ok I'll try the patch then.  Thanks for your help.